# Write the dataframe in loop to Multiple Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 500 excel files, from each file I have to skip starting 4 rows and select few columns. 
Either I can create new excel file for each file with particular columns, or i can push the data in SQL Server.

I need to create one function that can read all files and do the required process and give me output either in excel or SQL.

Comment: I have processed one single file with the following code:
file = 'OD_SALARY REGISTER_NOV_2016.xlsx' 
df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows = 4)
col_list = ['Emp Code',
 'Emp Name',
 'Net Salary',
 'Gross Earnings',
 'Provident Fund',
 'Provident Fund_A',
 'Profession Tax',
 'ESIC Deduction',
 'ESIC Deduction_A',
 'Gross Deductions',
 'Net Salary','Salary Bank',
 'Salary Account No',
 'IFSC Code',
 'PAN',
 'Location',
 'PF_Membership_No',
 'State For PT']
df.to_excel('File_1.xlsx', columns = col_list)

Comment: I don't get why this is a pandas question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's convenient to use [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) library for working with the file system.
The function `clean_one` is from your code with minor changes. The function `clean_all` applies `clean_one` to all file in the `root` directory (which is in my code ['os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) [current working directory]):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def clean_one(path, n):
    df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows = 4)
    col_list = ['Emp Code', 'Emp Name', 'Net Salary', 'Gross Earnings', 'Provident Fund',
                'Provident Fund_A', 'Profession Tax', 'ESIC Deduction', 'ESIC Deduction_A',
                'Gross Deductions', 'Net Salary','Salary Bank', 'Salary Account No',
                'IFSC Code', 'PAN', 'Location', 'PF_Membership_No', 'State For PT']
    df.to_excel('File_%d.xlsx' % n, columns = col_list)

def clean_all(root):
    for n, filepath in enumerate(os.listdir(root)):
        path = os.path.join(root, filepath)
        clean_one(path, n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = os.getcwd() # Replace it with necessary directory
    clean_all(root)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for